# Bash script to start a process, grep a line, then kill it

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking to get the version number of an app that doesn't have any kind of --version option.

I'm looking for a bash script that will start the process (it runs until killed), grep it's version number and then kill it.

Something like:

```
./server | grep version | kill $PID
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Hmmm....what is the application for something like this? and kill what? The thing that runs indefinitely?

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: Is this a one time thing or are you going to have to do this many times?

Comment: many times, I'm pulling a file from a remote location and discovering which version it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
./server | grep version | head -n 1 && kill $PID
```

The head will stop the pipe after it has found 1 result.

If you want to capture the variable you should be able to do:

```
version=`./server | grep version | head -n 1` && kill $PID
echo $version
```

Edit: The suggestions for 'strings' is a better path if viable.

Comment: Or use grep -m 1 and avoid the head -n 1

Answer (score 2):

Does the version string follow any reasonable format?  You might try running `strings` against the binary and see if you can build a pattern to match the version string.

Otherwise this gets a little hacky in bash.  I'd probably do something like:

```
./server | grep version &>/tmp/out.$$ &
sleep 10  # <-- however long it takes for version to come out.
kill %1
```

**Edit:** Tarrant's answer is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to run and kill it this way, or could you find the version by running strings over the binary?

Otherwise:

```
./server | grep user | kill `pgrep -P $$ server`
```

...should do the trick.